# Perl regex to capture with a optional delimiter

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to filter a Wikipedia dump using perl regex on the template pattern:

```
{{tl|a|b|c}}
```

I want to capture `a` and `b` where `a`, `b`, `c`, and so on can be any set of UTF-8 characters that does not include `|` or `}`.  There may be an unknown number of sets before the final '`}}`', but there will always be at least two (`a` and `b`).  So you could also get:

`{{tl|a|b}}`

or `{{tl|a|b|c|d}}`

Being a regex novice, I first thought trying `/\{\{tl\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|?\}\}/`

This gives the correct full match and first capture, but fails with the second capture, returning `b|c|d` because it won't find `|}`.  I need to tell it to look for something in between `|` and `}`, but only when it finds `|`.  It seems there should be a simple way with solve this, but I'm getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way `\{\{[^|}]*(?:\|[^|}]*)*\}\}`
but won't get captures.

Explained

```
 \{\{         # Open {{
 [^|}]*       # Optional, not | or }
 (?:          # Group start
      \|           # |
      [^|}]*       # Optional not | or }
 )*           # Group end, optional 0 to many times
 \}\}         # Close }}
```

Or, use the `\G` anchor and get the results in group 1

`(?:\G(?!\A)|\{\{)([^|}]*)(?=(?:\|[^|}]*)*\}\})(?:\||\}\})`

```
 (?:
      \G 
      (?! \A )
   |  
      \{\{                    # Open {{
 )

 ( [^|}]* )              # (1), Data

 (?=                     # Assert this is valid
      (?:
           \|                      # |
           [^|}]*                  # Optional not | or }
      )*                      # Group end, optional 0 to many times
      \}\}                    # Close }}
 )                       # End Assert

 (?:
      \|                      # Consume |
   |                        # or
      \}\}                    # Consume Close }}
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  The answer comes from using the `(?:pattern)` for "clustering, not capturing" a group. (from the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)).  Using this allows you to create groups that we can check for without capturing - in this case a choice between `}}` or `|c|d}}`. So, as a regex the answer is:

`/\{\{tl\|([^\|]+?)\|(.+?)(?:\}\}|\|[^\}]+?\}\})/`

The first part is similar to what I had before with `/\{\{tl\|` identifying the first part of the template and `([^\|]+?)\|` identifying the first capture and to stop with `|`.  The next part sets up the second capture `(.+?)` which is delimited by the choice of either `\}\}` OR `\|[^\}]+?\}\}` from inside the `(?:  )` construct.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: For this, you only need to escape the pipe outside classes. Your regex will match "`{{tl|a|b{{tl|a|b|c|d}}`|c|d}}" right now. If you say _oh, this will never be in a form like that_ then you can drop trying to validate the overall form and just get what you need. `tl\|([^|{}]+)\|([^|{}]+)` Otherwise, right now, your regex is not a valid form checker.

Comment: @sln I think I should have been more specific.  Although forms like you describe with templates inside of templates are common for something like an `Infobox`, I was actually working on doing a substitute for a  `convert` template where I wanted the whole expression between `{{ }}` to be replaced by `a b`.  I am still learning SO. Should I rewrite the question to reflect this?  Also, you clearly know more about regex than I do.  Is there a better way to accomplish this? (or do I need to clarify the question first?)

Comment: It's up to you how you ask the question that you know more about the subject on. The more specific, the more specific answers you'll get. I sometimes will make comments on obvious pitfalls as a helping gesture.